# How to verify color in selenium ide

Tags: selenium, ide

I have a text on the website that is green color. How can I verify in selenium ide that text is green? ( not any other color)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried assert element present command with xpath and colpr code in target but it works regardless of what color I choose , so it wasnt right

Answer (score 0):

if your text have style attribute, or class, who define the green color you can use ccs selector directly...

see [css selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp)

Or you can use integrated selenium functions [see here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/support_packages/working_with_colours/)